# CGContextClear Error in ios6

Tags: ios6, gif, animated-gif, ios6.1

I am getting this error while creating a gif. This error is not occurring in IOS5 but occurs in IOS6.

: The function `CGContextClear' is obsolete and will be removed in an upcoming update. Unfortunately, this application, or a library it uses, is using this obsolete function, and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system performance.